# Getting all values from a list with linq instead of foreach

Tags: c#, linq

There are a lot of questions relating to replace foreach with linq and the answer is mostly "don't linq is for querying collections not modifying them"

However, I want to know if we can use linq to simply get everything in a list, and then modify a second collection with that information.

```
foreach (var x in list1) dict1[x] = dict1.ContainsKey(x) ? dict1[x]++ : 1;
```

I want to know if we can get rid of the foreach and use a linq expression, because we aren't modifying the data in list1 so I don't believe it breaks the "rules."

Comment: In the example above, you're still not really "querying" the list. A Linq query returns something - the result of the query or some transformed or mapped result. This isn't modifying the list, but it's not querying either. It's just doing something using each value of the list as an argument. You could use `.ForEach` which looks like Linq, but it's really just a method of `List<T>`. `list.ForEach(x => dict1.ContainsKey(x) ? dict1[x]++ : 1);`

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the .ForEach https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Comment: Me either. It only makes sense if the function argument is itself a parameter. Otherwise it's just a funny way to do what you could already do with a loop. And even if the function is a parameter, you could still do it with a loop.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about turning the statement inside out and starting with dict1.ContainsKey(list1.Any.....) but couldn't make it work. There is nothing wrong with the loop, but it bugs me because I feel like I should be able to get rid of it.

Comment: You can make a method (as Eric Lippert mentioned), but I prefer to fight the Linqy-ness and just use a loop.`public static class ForEachExtensions
    {
        public static void ForEach<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, Action<T> action)
        {
            foreach (var item in collection) action(item);
        }
    }`

Comment: @ScottHannen Why advocate that the OP do something that you agree is not a good idea?  If you think it's not a good idea *don't suggest other people do it*.

Comment: @Servy I'm not advocating it. Why demonstrate it? Because it fits in a comment, that's why. I should really add some smileys to that. :) :) :)

Comment: @ScottHannen But you *were* advocating it.  Not that demonstrating it would be any different.  And advocating a solution you don't think is a good idea "because it fits in a comment" is pretty odd logic.

Comment: @Servy - I'm not sure how  saying I prefer not to do something is advocating it. :) :) I expressly disavow any and all use of the extension method I posted three comments ago. Don't do it. Really. Don't. :) :)

Comment: @ScottHannen Posting some code and telling people to use it, and then telling them that it's a bad idea and that they shouldn't use it in another comment 10 comments down in the chain, doesn't exactly fix the problem.  Advocating something you think is a bad idea is problematic even if you say at some point a long ways down that it's not a good idea.

Comment: But I said in the original comment that I wouldn't do it. I think that made it perfectly clear that they shouldn't do it, even in the context of that comment. :) :) :) :)

Comment: @ScottHannen If you think it's a bad idea then  *why are you advocating people do it*?  Just don't suggest things that you think are a bad idea.  Best case they realize you were just wasting their time by suggesting an idea they knew was bad, worst case they don't realize you were suggesting an idea you knew was bad and actually take your advice.  Either way, there's no good outcome.

Comment: @servy - I explicitly advocated *not* doing it. I take a firm stand against it. It goes against everything I stand for.  :) :) :) :-o

Comment: This is getting a little silly, @Servy I was never tempted to use ScottHannen's extension (though I do appreciate the option) as it doesn't remove the loop, it just moves it.

Comment: @JaneDoe That's all any LINQ, or LINQ-style operation ever does.  LINQ isn't magic.  They're all just loops that do a bit of extra stuff, and usually not that much extra either.  But anyway, while it's good that you realized the code isn't something to use, it means there was no benefit to posting the solution.  Again, the best case solution was wasting your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If dict is empty you could use LINQ like this to construct it:

```
var dict = list1.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Count());
```

Comment: This is exactly what I felt like I was missing, thanks!